# Pass Class as function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am just having some fun and making a library similar to LINQ in C#. I am attempting to create the `ofType()` method, that filters through the existing list and only returns an array that match the type specified.

What I have so far:

```
export class JSLinqArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  constructor(arr?: Array<T>) {
    super(...arr);
  }

  ofType = <U>(type: U): JSLinqArray<U> => {
    const output = new JSLinqArray<U>();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (this[i] instanceof type) {
        output.push(<any>this[i]);
      }
    }
    return output;
  }

  toArray = function (): T[] {
    const temp: T[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      temp.push(this[i]);
    }
    return temp;
  }
}



const mixedArr = new JSLinqArray<string | number>(['test1', 1, 2, 'test2']);

const test = mixedArr.ofType(String);
console.log(test.toArray());
```

How can I pass `String` or `Number` or even a `CustomClass` generic type reference through the `ofType` method so that I can use the `instanceof` comparison properly?

Right now the point of failure is at the if statement in the `ofType` method. `The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.`

Comment: What's going wrong with the code you've got so far (other than `.toArray()` being misspelled `.ToArray`)?

Comment: @Pointy I edited it in at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% confident in my answer, so take that as the disclaimer.

One issue I can see is that the javascript `Number` type is not the same as the primitive `number` type. `String` and `string` are not the same either.

Because of that it will not be possible to pass a number, and expect an instance of Number.

Comment: but if the OP would get away from the troubled little child called `instanceof` and use `.constructor` - then it would work like a charm!

Comment: @RandyCasburn what aspect of the constructor would I call while allowing it to remain generic? `constructor.name`?

Comment: @RandyCasburn but JavaScript primitives don't have a "constructor" property; they don't have *any* properties.  Now, it might not be a problem for the OP's admittedly "play" purposes to not be able to distinguish between string values and String instances, so that would be a possible solution.

Comment: Please re-read my answer: `.constructor` will force the runtime to coerce the primitive value into the Object. You can verify in the console `"String".constructor`

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` is not reliable in JavaScript for type checking purposes.

**Change**

```
if (this[i] instanceof type)
```

**To**

```
if (this[i].constructor === type)
```

The reason this works is because it will force the runtime to coerce the primitive value into the Object type. The constructor will then match correctly.